# using separate to divide column containing date format

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data set with columns containing a date and test-value

```
Dataset
ColumnA
03.01.19 3,0
02.02.18 2,0
01.03.17 1,0
```

I need them separated in a date-column and a value-column:

```
Dataset
date        value
03.01.19    3,0
02.02.18    2,0
01.03.17    1,0

separate(Dataset, "ColumnA", 
                  into = c("date","value"), 
                         )
```

but it gives me new columns like this and discards the rest of the information:

```
Dataset
date        value
03          01
02          02
01          03
```

How do I correct this?

I have tried `tidyr`:

```
separate(Dataset, "ColumnA", 
                  into = c("date","value")
```

I have also tried changing the space between date and value and specifying it
with the `sep = ""` argument.

```
ColumnA
03.01.19/3,0
02.02.18/2,0
01.03.17/1,0

separate(Dataset, "ColumnA", 
                  into = c("date","value"), 
                     sep= "/"    )
```

Comment: Did you try `sep=" "`?!(Note the space)

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data with `dput(head(df_name))`?

Comment: Space delimited, or go for string length of 8, skip one and grab the rest.

Answer (score 1):

`splitstackshape` does this for you and I am sure there are other packages too. `cSplit` is the function you are looking for.

```
cSplit(Data,"ColumnA", " ")

## OutPut

ColumnA_1 ColumnA_2
03.01.19       3,0
02.02.18       2,0
01.03.17       1,0
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

After reading the data as shown later, you could proceed within the `tidyverse` as shown below(`rename` as desired):

```
  df %>% 
   mutate(Date=row.names(.)) %>% 
   filter(Date!="ColumnA") %>% 
   select(Date,everything()) %>% 
   rename(date=Date,value=Dataset)

  date      value
1 03.01.19   3,0
2 02.02.18   2,0
3 01.03.17   1,0
```

**Original** (purely base):

We can use `read.table`:

```
df<-read.table(text="Dataset
ColumnA
03.01.19 3,0
02.02.18 2,0
01.03.17 1,0",header=T,sep=" ",as.is=T,fill=T)
```

Then(rename and reorder as desired):

```
df$ColumnA<-row.names(df)
rownames(df)<-NULL
df[2:nrow(df),]
 Dataset   ColumA
2     3,0 03.01.19
3     2,0 02.02.18
4     1,0 01.03.17
```